# iotagent-json tutorial error

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

During this tutorial: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/blob/master/docs/stepbystep.md

When I execute the curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
"value" : "300"
}' 'http://localhost:1026/v1/contextEntities/LivingRoomSensor/attrs/sleepTime'
```

I'm getting this error response:

```
{
"orionError" : {
"code" : "400",
"reasonPhrase" : "Bad Request",
"details" : "service not found"
}
}
```

How to fix this?

Cumps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing:

```
localhost:1026/v1/contextEntities/LivingRoomSensor/attrs/…
```

to

```
localhost:1026/v1/contextEntities/LivingRoomSensor/attribute‌​s/…
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are "mixing" URL styles from NGSIv1 and NGSIv2 :) I mean, it should be either:

```
/v2/entities/LivingRoomSensor/attrs/sleepTime
```

or

```
/v1/contextEntities/LivingRoomSensor/attributes/sleepTime
```

My recomendation is always to use NGSIv2, as it is a more powerfull, flexible and simple version of the context management API that Orion Context Broker provides.